# PHP 7.1 'A non-numeric value encountered' with Twig 1.35

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, twig, php-7.1

I am using the Twig template engine and I have just upgraded my PHP version to 7.1.

I now get the following warning when rendering any page:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: A non-numeric value encountered

Filename: Twig/Environment.php(469) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 91

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/application/third_party/Twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(471) : eval()'d code
Line: 91
Function: _error_handler

File: /var/ww...

...

...html/index.php
Line: 320
Function: require_once

0" />
```

This looks to be referring to the following line in the Twig/Environment.php file

```
eval('?>'.$content);
```

Here's the content of the $content variable:

```
parent = $this->loadTemplate("base.twig", "twig/index.twig", 1);
        $this->blocks = array(
            'content' => array($this, 'block_content'),
        );
    }

    protected function doGetParent(array $context)
    {
        return "base.twig";
    }

    protected function doDisplay(array $context, array $blocks = array())
    {
        $this->parent->display($context, array_merge($this->blocks, $blocks));
    }

    // line 3
    public function block_content($context, array $blocks = array())
    {
        // line 4
        echo "        
";
    }

    public function getTemplateName()
    {
        return "twig/index.twig";
    }

    public function isTraitable()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getDebugInfo()
    {
        return array (  31 => 4,  28 => 3,  11 => 1,);
    }

    /** @deprecated since 1.27 (to be removed in 2.0). Use getSourceContext() instead */
    public function getSource()
    {
        @trigger_error('The '.__METHOD__.' method is deprecated since version 1.27 and will be removed in 2.0. Use getSourceContext() instead.', E_USER_DEPRECATED);

        return $this->getSourceContext()->getCode();
    }

    public function getSourceContext()
    {
        return new Twig_Source("", "twig/index.twig", "/var/www/html/application/views/twig/index.twig");
    }
}
```

I'm just not too sure where the non-numeric value is. Any ideas please?

I'm not sure it's relevant but I'm using Codeigniter 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems in this case I just needed to trawl through my twig file and find the non-numeric value and give it a default of 0 if it's not set.

```
<input type="hidden" name="vals" value="{{ (my_var * 'now'|date('Y') }}" />
```

Becomes

```
<input type="hidden" name="vals" value="{{ (my_var|default(0) * 'now'|date('Y') }}" />
```